# If query check if innterText is a certain string is not working

Tags: javascript

firstly I marked the considered are in my JavaScript Code up. When I am clicking on the start button two functions will be executed, the startDrive() function and the buttonAndTimer function, the button will turn into pause, if I am pressing pause, the button text will turn into resume and the executed functions are be stoped or they should respectively. buttonAndTimer will be stopped but startDrive not even though I coded that it should with "if actioner.innerText = 'Resume' but it is not working. But when I code "if actioner.innerText = 'Pause'" startDive() ist stopping. That is not the desired result i want to stop startDrive() when the actioner.innerText = 'Resume'. What I am doing worng?

```
window.onload = function() {
 //global variables
  const span = document.querySelector('span');
  const actioner = document.getElementById('actioner');
  const reseter = document.getElementById('reseter');
  let interval = null;
  let y = 3.90;
  let reversal = 20
  const output = document.querySelector('output');
  
  //If start is clicked
  actioner.addEventListener('click',() => {
    buttonAndTimer();
    startDrive();
    
    });// end of func
  
  function buttonAndTimer() {
    if(!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        span.innerText = parseInt(span.innerText) +1 +' sec';
      },1000)
       pause = actioner.innerText = 'Pause';
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      actioner.innerText = 'Resume';
    }
  }
  //calculating price
  function startDrive() {
    output.innerHTML = y.toFixed(2)+'€';
    timerId = setInterval(() => {
      if(y < reversal) {
        y += 0.14375;
      } else if(y > reversal) {
        y += 0.103125;
      }
      output.innerHTML = y.toFixed(2) + "€";
      }
    ,5000);

   /*Considered area */if (actioner.innerText == 'Resume') {
      clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    
  }//end of func

  //reseter
  reseter.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = 0;
    span.innerText = 0;
    actioner.innerText = 'Start';
  })// end of func
  
  
  
  
}//end of window.load
```

```
<div id = "box">
<button class = 'button' id = 'actioner'>Start</button>
<output></output>
<button class = 'button' id = 'reseter'>Reset</button>
<span>0</span>
</div>
```

```
#box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 30px;
  padding:30vh;
}

span {
  color:#74bde0;
  width:15vh;
  border:1px solid;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width:20vh; 
}

.button {
  border:none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:#74bde0;
  
  
}

output {
  border: 1px solid;
border-color:#74bde0 ;
border-radius: 5px;
height: 10vh;
width: 30vh;
text-align: center;
color:#74bde0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In startDrive i added condition !=Resume for stopping the timer

In Reset click i added these

```
clearInterval(timerId); // clearing the interval with timerid
timerId = 0; // setting the timerid to 0
output.innerHTML = ""; // setting the output control to ""
y = 3.90; // reset
```

```
window.onload = function() {
  //global variables
  const span = document.querySelector('span');
  const actioner = document.getElementById('actioner');
  const reseter = document.getElementById('reseter');
  let interval = null;
  let timerId = null;
  let y = 3.90; 
  let reversal = 20
  const output = document.querySelector('output');

  //If start is clicked
  actioner.addEventListener('click', () => {
    buttonAndTimer();
    startDrive();

  }); // end of func

  function buttonAndTimer() {
    if (!interval) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        span.innerText = parseInt(span.innerText) + 1 + ' sec';
      }, 1000)
      pause = actioner.innerText = 'Pause';
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
      actioner.innerText = 'Resume';
    }
  }
  //calculating price
  function startDrive() {



    if (actioner.innerText != 'Resume') { 
      output.innerHTML = y.toFixed(2) + '€';
      timerId = setInterval(() => {
        if (y < reversal) {
          y += 0.14375;
        } else if (y > reversal) {
          y += 0.103125;
        }
        output.innerHTML = y.toFixed(2) + "€";
      }, 5000);
    }
    /*Considered area */
    if (actioner.innerText == 'Resume') {

      clearInterval(timerId);
    }

  } //end of func

  //reseter
  reseter.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = 0;
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = 0;
    span.innerText = 0;
    output.innerHTML = "";
    actioner.innerText = 'Start';
    y = 3.90;
  }) // end of func




} //end of window.load
```

Hope it solve it you purpose!

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain your step

Comment: In Reset Button click event , Reseted the y value(because the y value not reseted in setinterval()),cleared the output value to null,reseting the timerID

Moved the timerID as global variable. so that i can reset the timerID anywhere.

you had difficulty in "if actioner.innerText = 'Resume'  because, you are executing   buttonAndTimer()
before startDrive(), so it changes the text of the actioner  button first
and  in startDrive you cannot get text as start, you will get only pause,resume.